# Java Scanner Sorting

Tags: java, массивы

Программа считывает с файла числа типа `int`. Потом происходит поиск четных чисел. Но в файле есть число `315` (естественно, оно нечетное), но в консоли оно появляется (причем другие нечетные числа я удалил из массива). Когда четные числа я сортирую при поиске (`Scanner.nextInt`), то число `315` не появляется в консоли и все работает как надо.

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));// напишите тут ваш код
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(reader.readLine());
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
        ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (inputStream.available() > 0)
        {
            while(scanner.hasNextInt())
            {
                int data = scanner.nextInt();
                integerArrayList.add(data);
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < integerArrayList.size(); i++)
        {
            if (integerArrayList.get(i) % 2 != 0)
            {
                integerArrayList.remove(i);
            }
        }


        for (Integer items : integerArrayList)
        {
            System.out.println(items);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ответ я дал. Но на заметку: на JavaRush есть свой форум, где помогают по задачам: help.javarush.ru.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя так удалять в цикле элементы массива. Удаляя, ты изменяешь нумерацию. Попробуй ввести подряд несколько нечетных чисел, у тебя они через одно будут выведены на экран. Удалять надо через итератор:

```
ListIterator<Integer> iterator = integerArrayList.listIterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                int a = iterator.next();
                if(a % 2 != 0)
                    iterator.remove();
            }
```

Еще можно впилить костыль в твой код, если добавить уменьшение i в случае удаления:

```
if (integerArrayList.get(i) % 2 != 0)
            {
                integerArrayList.remove(i--);
            }
```

Но, повторюсь, это хоть и будет работать, но так делать категорически не стоит.